# How do I get a slider control with 2 values?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get a slider control with 2 values?

|...........

Value 1: 100
Value 2: 0

......|.....

Value 1: 50
Value 2: 50

...........|

Value 1: 0
Value 2: 100

Edit: these are just examples when dragged there and not 'step'

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbsNx.jpg)

[Html Slider:](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_slider)

Comment: `var value2 = 100 - value1;` ?

Comment: the numbers are just placeholders

Comment: If they both rely on the same slider, you should be able to calculate value 2 by knowing value 1.

Comment: Is it possible to make a slider control such that when the slider is in the middle , the value is not half of the range. Eg. Slider at most left , Value = 0. Slider at middle , Value = 2. Slider at Most right , value = 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need both values regardless the `min` and `max` and without knowing their values you can expand @Weedoze answer to reflect this

```js
function updateTextInput(val) {
 var value1 = Number(val) - Number(document.getElementById('range').min);
 document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML = "value1: "+value1;
 var value2 = Number(document.getElementById('range').max) - Number(val);
 document.getElementById('value2').innerHTML = "value2: "+value2;
}
```

```html
0<input id="range" type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="200" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">200
<br />
<p id="value1"></p>
<p id="value2"></p>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make a slider control such that when the slider is in the middle , the value is not half of the range.

Comment: Can you give us an example? Imagine a range from 200 to 400, what value do you want when the slider is in the center?

Comment: A slider that has 2 ranges 1.01 - 9500 and 94 - 0.01(left to right) when the slider is at half its 1st value is 2, and 2nd value is 47.5. Like this http://imgur.com/a/uRcFQ

Comment: What is the logic behind that? In that case how do you calculate the 2 and 47.5 values, what is the math in that?

Comment: It's a random number game script. It generates a random number from 1-100. The slider lets you select the odds of winning. If you roll below value 2 you get value 1* 5 points. If you roll above value 2, you lose 5 points. Value 2 selects the odds of winning, so when the odds go to a scenario where you have to roll 0 to win, you get 5*9500 points.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a "step"-property to the input

```
<input
    type="range"
    name="points"
    id="points"
    step="50"
    value="50"
    min="0"
    max="100">
```

value1 would be the input value and value2 = 100 - value1

Answer (score 0):

```js
function updateTextInput(val) {
  document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = val;
}
```

```html
0
<input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">100
<br />
<p id="value"></p>
```